# Create ios Swift Framework independent of Xcode Compiler Version

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, xcode11

We have a Chat API framework. We provide .framework file through cocoapods as we don't want to show the code. Problem we faced that we have to create .framework file for each Xcode version as each Xcode has different compiler version

11.0 => 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7)

11.1 => 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7)

11.2 => 5.1.2 (swiftlang-1100.0.278 clang-1100.0.33.9)

11.3 => 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15)

11.3.1 => 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15)

11.4 => 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)

11.4.1 => 5.2.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.6 clang-1103.0.32.51)

When we try to import framework build with Xcode 11.4 in Xcode 11.0, it gives error "Module compiled with Swift Version 5.2 compiler cannot be imported in compiler version 5.1

Any Solution for this as we can not ask our clients to change Xcode Versions.

Comment: Why don't you find the minimal swift version you wanna support (check your user base find the lowest swift version they are consuming your framework with) and stick with that, till you find something paradigm shifting change in latest swift version. In case you have to shift to latest swift version than make that the minimal swift version you support.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari it is not about Swift Version. We have set Swift version as 4.2. It is about Xcode compiler version to compile a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can distribute you framework via XCFramework, it was introduced on WWDC19.

Code to create XCFramework is as bellow,

1. Create an archive for iOS platform

   ```
    xcodebuild archive -workspace {YourWorkspace}.xcworkspace \
      -scheme {Scheme} \
      -sdk iphoneos \
      -archivePath "./archives/ios_devices.xcarchive" \
      BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
      SKIP_INSTALL=NO | xcpretty
   ```
2. Create an archive for iOS-Simulator platform

   ```
    xcodebuild archive  -workspace YourWorkspace.xcworkspace \
      -scheme {Scheme} \
      -sdk iphonesimulator \
      -archivePath "./archives/ios_simulators.xcarchive" \
      BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
      SKIP_INSTALL=NO | xcpretty
   ```
3. Create an XCFramework from Archives

   ```
    xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
      -framework ./archives/ios_devices.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/{Your Framework}.framework \
      -framework ./archives/ios_simulators.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/{Your Framework}.framework \
      -output build/{Your Framework}.xcframework | xcpretty
   ```

[how to build xcframework](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-build-xcframework-with-xcode-b3d0b3c08f43)

[WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/)